# Unexpected token: while at line:

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy and don't have hands-on experience in Java. Could anyone answer my naive question in the below code.

```
class StudentMap { 

def student_map=new HashMap<String,String>()

def answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'  

while (answer=='Y') { 
    get_student()
    answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continue Y/N\n' 
    }

def add_student(String name,String age)
     {  
        student_map << ["${name}":"${age}"]  
     }   

def get_student()
    {  
        def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
        def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
        add_student(name,age) 
    }
 print student_map
} 
def Student_Map = new StudentMap()
```

I am getting the below error

> 1 compilation error:
>
> unexpected token: while at line: 7, column: 5

I checked the brackets but they seem fine. Could anyone tell me whats the error in this code.
I just want to create a HashMap each time and store students information like age and name
Basically when ever i run this i would want to create a HashMap of students information and print it.

Also could anyone suggest any good sites offering Groovy Examples from Beginner to Expert as most of the results that i found online are more java programmer friendly.

Thanks in advance

*****This Answer Contains 2 Updates*****

Update 1

Thanks for the reply Nathan.. Below is the code i had initially written to achieve the following :: 1.Create a Hashmap of students everytime the code is run 2.Ask the user to enter Student information 3.When no more students are to be added display the HashMap

My code WITHOUT using class is

```
answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'

while (answer=='Y') { 
get_student()
answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continue Y/N\n' 
}

def add_student(String name,String age)
 {  

    def student_map=new HashMap<String,String>()
    student_map << ["${name}":"${age}"]  
 }   

def get_student()
{  
    def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
    def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
    add_student(name,age) 
}
```

Apart from displaying, which should not be a big problem this code runs fine but i guess it creates a HashMap for each student entry which i do not want. And if i declare the def student_map=new HashMap() outside the add_student function the function cannot reference it. Thats the reason i thought of making a Student class so everytime i make a object of the class student_map through def Student_Map = new StudentMap(), it would create a Student_map object whose property would be the HashMap student_map which can have two actions

1.Get student information from user through get_student() function. 2.Add the student information into the student_map HashMap using add_student(String name,String age) function.

When no more addition is required display the contents of the HashMap student_map.

Please let me know if my understanding and implementation is correct and efficient.

Update 2 on the Same:

I tried to run the code as suggested by putting the while and print inside a method main() which compiled fine but is still not logically correct it seems as whenever i run the code it executes and does not ask for user input.

Below is the updated code i am trying to run to achieve what i mentioned in the above update of this post.

```
class StudentMap {

void main(String[] args) {

answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'  

def student_map=new HashMap<String,String>()

while (answer=='Y') { 
    get_student()
    answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 
 }

}
def add_student(String name,String age) {
student_map << ["${name}":"${age}"]
}

def get_student()
{  
    def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
    def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
    add_student(name,age) 
}
} def Student_Map = new StudentMap()
```

Result: StudentMap@7e54423

I removed the static in the void main function as it was giving me the below error.

Apparent variable 'answer' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes: You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context. You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling. You attempted to use a method 'answer' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.

Without the static keyword my code compiles fine. I suppose my object is getting created but is not behaving the way i want it to.

Could anyone please let me know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your `while` loop and `print student_map` statement, that are outside any method.

So, if you want to execute the while and print, put them inside a `main` method:

```
class StudentMap { 
    ...

    //something like
    static void main(String[] args) {
        while (answer=='Y') { 
            get_student()
            answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 
        }
        print student_map
    }
}
```

Groovy is a script language, so you don't need to put your code inside a class. Other option is remove the class declaration from your script.

Groovy reference: http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html

Comment: Thanks victor it now compiles fine but still am facing some issues. Could you please go through my latest post and let me know what i am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance